# yarn run build gives error directory not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg, vercel

I completed a blog in Next js and I uploaded it on github :
https://github.com/xspd3000/frontend

I want to deploy it on Vercel but it gave me error

```
    > Build error occurred
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:/projects/tailgradient/frontend/data/posts'] {
  type: 'Error',
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:/projects/tailgradient/frontend/data/posts'
}
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: You trying to deploy it with `C:/` in path, remove it from path and use `./`. It might solve your problem

Comment: this didnt worked